# Validation Errors Seeding Rails 3 w Seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

I have a Products model with several attributes (`customer_type`, `customer_name`, `dept_type` etc...) and I'm trying to seed it with some data.

I have the following in my `db/seeds.rb` file

```
 Product.create(customer_type:'Retailer', customer_name: 'Walmart', dept_type: 'Grocery')
```

I save the file then run `rake db:Seed` I get no error messages but when I load my app none of the data is present? what am i doing wrong here?

I also tried `rake db:setup` and `rake db:reset` each time it returns no error message but the data doesn't load.

Update
I modified my db seeds file to look like this

```
  Product.create!(customer_type:'Retailer', customer_name: 'Walmart', dept_type: 'Grocery')
```

when i run rake db:reset i get error "Validation failed: Customer type is not included in the list"

My Products Model file with validations

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible  :customer_type

   has_many :line_items
   has_many :orders, through: :line_items

   CUSTOMER_TYPES = ["Retailer", "Manufacturer"]
   validates :customer_type, inclusion: CUSTOMER_TYPES
```

I have tried seeding the db with both customer type values Retailer and Manufacturer no luck

Comment: Please show us your validations in your `Product` model.

Comment: @nathanvda      CUSTOMER_TYPES = ["Retailer", "Manufacturer"] validates :customer_type, inclusion: CUSTOMER_TYPES

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that your model is failing to save. You're ignoring any errors from the `create` call. Use `Product.create!` instead, and if your creation fails, it will raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks i am now getting an error that customer_type is not included. This is a required field in my model set up as a CUSTOMER_TYPES selection list I entered one of the selection options in the db seed file but it doesn't appear to take. any idea what i could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your syntax. 
Please try

`validates : customer_type, :inclusion => { :in => CUSTOMER_TYPES }` and it will work fine.

If I were you, I would be using `enums` for this type of scenario. Using `Enums` perfectly binds the column.